# Simple Regex Help

Tags: .net, regex, iis

How can I match strings without a dot in regex, for example, these should be matched:

```
a/b
אאא/תתת
a
b
c
ג
123/1
```

but these shouldn't:

```
abc.asp
ddd.css
style/main.css
```

For .NET Syntax. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex

```
^[^.]*$
```

matches a string not containing a dot.

Answer (score 0):

`[^.]` will match every character except the dot.